# Python copy a string for specified number of times

Tags: python, string, text, copy

I have the file phones.txt which contains phone numbers , one phone per line like this

```
00000000
1111111
222222
```

I want to create a python script which asks the user for how many folders he want to create then I want the script to calculate the number of folders and the number of lines in the file phones.txt then calculate how many times every number will be copied then copy it to the folders in the file phone.txt

Like if the user input 9 the script will devide 9 on the lines number which is 3 . That means that the first number will be copied to first 3 folder "1,2,3" and the second number will be copied to folders "4,5,6" and the last one to folders "7,8,9"

Now My code :-

```
folders = int(raw_input( "How many folders for perfix {0} : ".format(name)))
for i in range(folders):
    pathname = os.path.join(fullPath, str(i+1))
    os.mkdir( pathname )
    #### NOW WHAT TO DO HERE ? ####
```

I stopped in this place , any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
import math

# read the phone numbers from file
with open('phone.txt', 'r') as f:
    progs = f.read().splitlines()

folders = input( "How many folders for perfix {0} : ".format(name))
# calculate how many folders a number is in
# therefore use the highest possible number (e.g. if folders is 8 use 3)
num = int(math.ceil(float(folders)/len(progs)))

# loop through the number of folders to create
for i in xrange(folders):
    # create folder
    pathname = os.path.join(fullPath, str(i+1))
    os.mkdir( pathname )

    # create file
    filename = os.path.join(pathname, 'number.txt')
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(progs[i/num])
```

This also works for cases where the user input is not dividable by the number of `progs`.
E.g. if the user types 8 and there are 3 phone numbers the numbers will be added to the folders like this:

- `'00000000'` to folder 1,2,3
- `'1111111'`  to folder 4,5,6
- `'222222'`   to folder 7,8

Comment: Hi , there is one thing , progs is being taken from the file "phone.txt" , and your code is using it as a list ?

Comment: it should read the file phone.txt to get entires and it could be more that 3 lines

Comment: I replaced the code lines - now the phone numbers comes from a file. And the code can handle more than 3 lines.